# iOS App Termination - Reduce Possibility

Tags: ios

As I understand it is not possible to prevent an app from being terminated by iOS while running in background mode (e.g., going from Suspended to Not Running State).

Does enabling an app for "Background App Refresh" reduce the chances of this happening? e.g. in `Info.plist` just set "UIBackgroundModes=Fetch".

Would iOS give this priority over an app that does not have "Background App Refresh" enabled and terminate such an App first?

This is an iOS7 scenario.

Comment: Please be aware that `IOS` is **NOT** the same as `iOS`. You want `iOS` so I have edited your question accordingly.

Comment: Is there any reason you need to have your app running in the background all the time? Apple specifically discourages this as it uses precious system resources and battery life.

Comment: BackgroundAppRefresh (and most other background app modes) do not stop your app from being terminated. Instead the app registers to be "woken up" by the OS when the OS finds something that the app needs. Having said that, if you register for stuff that the app doesn't need then you're likely to be rejected by Apple. I know that the OS terminates apps in order to clear memory when it is tight for other apps. If you could reduce the memory usage of your app to be minimal than maybe you could get round it. But then it would be more work to start up. May as well just let it terminate.

Comment: @Fogmeister Id repost that as an answer so we can cross this off the list, no?!

Comment: @Daij-Djan done. It started out as a small comment but then just kept going. lol!

Answer (score 1):

BackgroundAppRefresh (and most other background app modes) do not stop your app from being terminated. Instead the app registers to be "woken up" by the OS when the OS finds something that the app needs.

Having said that, if you register for stuff that the app doesn't need then you're likely to be rejected by Apple.

I know that the OS terminates apps in order to clear memory when it is tight for other apps. If you could reduce the memory usage of your app to be minimal than maybe you could get round it.

Doing that though would be more work to start it up again. May as well just let it terminate.

One thing to work on (and spend a lot of time doing) is improving the start up time. Your app should start almost instantly anyway. If it doesn't there's a chance of being caught out by the Watchdog and terminated.

Terminating the app shouldn't be an issue, if it is then you need to fix something.